# Which Runtime and web hosting bundle do i need to host my AspNetCore 2.0.3 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0

When i have SDK version installed, all things are fine but for hosting my app, i had to install dotnet web hosting bundle along with the runtime. For each of the bundle, I use v2.0.3. But after I have installed later two, dotnet command isn't functioning although my SDK is still there. I'm using visual studio Code btw.[My installed Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mFJA.png) and after that dotnet command shows this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN71w.png)

Tried with different versions of SDK and Web hosing with runtime packages from [https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mFJA.png) but no result. My *.csproj file is below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.6"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.6"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" Version="4.5.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices" Version="4.5.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.5.1"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1"/>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0"/>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: The SDK/runtime and hosting bundle version numbers do not necessarily line up with the version of ASP.NET Core or .NET Core you're targeting. However, the latest 2.X versions will still support something like 2.0.3, so there's really no reason to not just go for the latest. FWIW, you should upgrade to at least 2.1, anyways, as that's the current LTS release. 2.0 is end of life and unsupported.

Comment: I have migrated the code to core 2.1 and installed the latest web host with runtime and my problem is solved. Thanks for the heads up.